# How to highlight lines of code in Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to debug a Visual C# program, and it would be helpful if I could highlight lines or do something similar to make them stand out.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Use [Bookmarks with Highlighting](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025144929/http://geekswithblogs.net/davewill/archive/2008/08/11/124363.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could use bookmarks for that (Ctrl+k, Ctrl+k). This will show an icon to the left of the text and also enable you to easily jump between your bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

use some third party tool,such like JetBrains ReSharper.

Comment: Sorry, you comment will be more helpful if you elaborate on this, maybe show screenshots. Otherwise I don't understand what you mean.